# My function returns an array with 3 arrays stored. How can I use/reference the elements in each inner array?

Tags: html, arrays, google-apps-script

I have this in my code.gs file:

```
function getDropdownMenus(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheets();
  var array1= ss[1].getRange(1,2,ss[1].getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheets();
 var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheets();
   var array3=ss2[0].getRange(1,1,ss2[0].getLastRow(),1).getValues();



  var array2temp= ss1[0].getRange(1,2,ss1[0].getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var array2=[];
  var j=0;

  for (var i = 0;i<array2temp.length;i++)
  {
    if(array2temp[i][0]=='')
    {}else
    {

    array2[j]=array2temp[i][0];
  j++;
  }
  }

  return [array1,array2,array3];
```

However, I'm not able to access array1[0][0], or any of the elements of array2 or array3 for that matter, in the HTML Index.html

This is Index.html

```
 <script>
      function onSuccess(info) {
        var select = document.getElementById('ddm1');
        var select1 = document.getElementById('ddm2');
var select2 = document.getElementById('ddm3');

        var newArray1= info[0];
        var newArray2= info[1];
       var newArray3=info[2];

             for(var i = 0; i<newArray2.length;i++)
        {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = newArray2[i];
        select1.options.add(option);

        }

        for(var i = 0; i<newArray1.length;i++)
        {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = newArray1[i];
        select.options.add(option);

        }

        for(var i = 0; i<newArray3.length;i++)
        {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = newArray3[i];
        select2.options.add(option);

        } 


      }

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDropdownMenus();

</script>
```

I've tried it removing the third array in the return part of the code.gs file and it works perfectly however I'm guessing it stores the arrays differently when it has 3 arrays instead?

Comment: I would have put them in an object and given each a name.

Comment: I see, how do you put them in an object? Is it similar to what ra89fi has done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a column, values are in this format, `[ [value], [value], [value]... ]`. You're using this array of arrays as regular array of elements in `onSuccess`. Try this code instead -

```
function getDropdownMenus() {
  var sp1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheets();
  // read col B, [ [value], [value], [value]... ] to [ value, value, value... ]
  var array1 = sp1[1].getRange(1, 2, sp1[1].getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  array1 = array1.map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });

  var sp3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheets();
  // read col A, [ [value], [value], [value]... ] to [ value, value, value... ]
  var array3 = sp3[0].getRange(1, 1, sp3[0].getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  array3 = array3.map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });

  var sp2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheets();
  // read col B, [ [value], [value], [value]... ] to [ value, value, value... ]
  var array2 = sp2[0].getRange(1, 2, sp2[0].getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  array2 = array2
    .map(function(el) {
      return el[0];
    })
    .filter(function(el) {
      // clean empty values
      return el != '';
    });

  return {
    one: array1,
    two: array2,
    three: array3
  };
}

function onSuccess(info) {
  var select = document.getElementById('ddm1');
  var select1 = document.getElementById('ddm2');
  var select2 = document.getElementById('ddm3');

  var newArray1 = info.one;
  var newArray2 = info.two;
  var newArray3 = info.three;

  for (var i = 0; i < newArray2.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = newArray2[i];
    select1.options.add(option);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < newArray1.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = newArray1[i];
    select.options.add(option);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < newArray3.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = newArray3[i];
    select2.options.add(option);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand what you did here. What are the  '.map' and .filter doing? I've never had to use them and also why are you using 'function(el)' and then returning 'el[0]'?

Comment: Is the return variable of 'getDropdownMenus()' an object?

Comment: Also I just tried it and it's the same problem. It works perfectly when I do 'return {one: array1, two:array2};'

However when I try 'return {one: array1, two:array2, three:array3};' it stops working

Comment: See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). We are reading sheet values by column and what returns is array of arrays. Here `map` creates an array out of array of arrays by having `function(el) { return el[0]; }` as callback function. Include array3 and log `info` in browser console to see what values are you getting. Could be sheet format issue, wrong values are read or in wrong format.

Comment: Hello, after further analysis it turned out that it was in fact a format factor. I was getting durations from the spreadsheet and when I formatted it in plain text it all worked perfectly. I appreciate your time. Thank you!